# Elementor Menu is not working on mobile with wp rocket delay js enable

Tags: wordpress, browser-cache, elementor

Elementor Menu is not working on mobile with wp rocket delay js enable. How to fix it?
Site URL: https://medicalmarketing.es/
[image]

Comment: I also have this problem, would love to know what files to exclude to get it working